# ASP.NET: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Customer.Person.PersonType'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I got this error when I debugged it to the `Shipping Form`. Could anyone tell me where I'm wrong ???
Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(SalesOrderHeader order,Customer customer ,FormCollection values)
        {
           // var order = new SalesOrderHeader();
            //var order1 = new SalesOrderDetail();
           // TryUpdateModel(order);
            ViewBag["PersonType"] = new SelectList(BikeDBs.Customers.Select(r => r.Person.PersonType));
       ...
```

View:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.Person.PersonType): 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Customer.Person.PersonType, ViewBag.PersonType as SelectList, "--Select List--",null)<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend passing your select list through a view model instead of a viewbag.  having said that you are setting the view bag wrong

```
ViewBag["PersonType"]
```

should be

```
ViewBag.PersonType
```

on your controller as well as your view

Comment: Ya He is right, you can Pass data from Controller to view with the use of ViewBag data you should be use ViewBag.PersonType try it.